# In JavaScript, how can you access a property of a superclass' instance?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

In JavaScript, how can I access a property of a superclass' instance? As an example, I'd like the "prop" of the superclass' instance set to "true", but this code creates and sets the "prop" of the subclass' instance to "true", leaving the superclass' instance's "prop" as false:

```
var SuperClass = function() {
    this.prop = true;
}

SuperClass.prototype.doStuff = function() { 
    if (this.prop) {
        console.log('SuperClass does A.');
    }
    else {
        console.log('SuperClass does B.');
    }
}

SuperClass.prototype.load = function() {
    this.prop = false;
}

SuperClass.prototype.setProp = function(val) {
    this.prop = val;
}

function SubClass() {
    SuperClass.call(this);
}

SubClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

SubClass.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    SuperClass.prototype.doStuff();

    if (this.prop) {
        console.log('SubClass does A.');
    }
    else {
        console.log('SubClass does B.');
    }
}

SubClass.prototype.load = function() {
    SuperClass.prototype.load();
}

var anObject = new SubClass();
anObject.load();
anObject.setProp(true);
anObject.doStuff();
```

Currently, the output is "SuperClass does B. SubClass does A.", which is not the desired result. How do I properly set the value of "prop" so that they both do "A"? I'm not trying to create a new property in the subclass' instance, I want to access the existing property in the  superclass' instance.

Thanks!

Additionally, can you access a superclass' instance's properties from a subclass' constructor? Or does the subclass need to be instantiated first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SubClass.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    SuperClass.prototype.doStuff();
```

You aren't giving the super class any context, so the function isn't acting on the current object (i.e. `this` will be wrong).

Instead try:

```
SubClass.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    SuperClass.prototype.doStuff.call(this);
```

This gives me the desired output:

```
SuperClass does A.
SubClass does A.
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see! So anytime I call a superclass' method by doing .call(this), it'll use the properties of the subclass' instance first and it won't even matter if there are also properties of the same name in the superclass' instance. Thank you so much!

Comment: There is only one property `prop` in the object, not a separate one for the super and subclass.  Accessing `this.prop` from functions in either prototype will confirm this.  What you were doing was calling the superclass function _without the scope of the object_, so inside the superclass method `this` will have been the global scope rather than the object you thought it was.  With there being no `prop` in the global scope, `this.prop` is undefined, `if(this.prop)` is false, and you hit the else branch.